# Override publish properties from parent build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, openapi-generator, maven-publish, gradle-multi-project-build

I'm trying to automate publishing of an openapi generated java client.

Its a huge pain because the generated client configures its own publishing config in the generated build.gradle file. Eg: line 82-102 in the generated `java-client/build.gradle` file:

```
} else {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
               artifactId = 'openapi-java-client'
               from components.java
            }
        }
    }

    task execute(type:JavaExec) {
       main = System.getProperty('mainClass')
       classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

I try to override these settings in a parent build.gradle file like so:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = 'com.mycompany'
                artifactId = 'ARTIFACT-NAME'
                version = "v7.1.2"
                from components.java
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                credentials {
                    username = System.env.ART_USERNAME
                    password = System.env.ART_PASSWORD
                }

                url "https://artifactory.myartifactoryurl/artifactory/maven"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Parent `settings.gradle` inclues the line: `include('lib', 'java-client')`

This doesn't work because apparently overriding doesnt work....

Error message "Maven publication 'maven' cannot include multiple components"

On the line 'from components.java' in 'java-client/build.gradle' it throws the error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':java-client'.
> Maven publication 'maven' cannot include multiple components
```

I don't know how they expect us to configure publishing without some sort of externalized config like npm has via the `.npmrc` file.

Does anyone have any tips and tricks for overriding the maven-publish settings already defined in a subproject without modifying the subproject directly?

Thanks for any help! This is a huge PITA the maven-plugin should address in my opinion.

Comment: OpenAPI Generator lets you [override the templates](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating#modifying-templates) for the generated files. So you can try using your own template for the `build.gradle` file. I think the original `build.gradle` template for the Java client is this one: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/build.gradle.mustache

Comment: Unfortunately that couples the generation to a specific version of the generator - the template version file I copy and modify. But that's definitely something I considered. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: hi @TheJeff, you found a way by now to achieve that? Have the same PITA, same need. Want to avoid coupling and gradle/maven complexity. Tried lots of approaches, all of them failed, so I gave up and came up with a kind of brute force solution which completely ignores the generated build script (https://github.com/Vertama-GmbH/divi-openapi-okhttp-gson-client). 

Still, I would like to know if there is any reasonable way to achieve this seemingly logical and basically very simple task, like publishing a piece of OSS to a public repo. Let us know if you found a way to do it.

Comment: @DirkLüsebrink I'll post an answer to this, yes I solved it.

Comment: @DirkLüsebrink looking at my code, I don't remember how I solved it.. I do remember that this setting was a game changer for me though.. additionalProperties:
  omitGradleWrapper: "true"
Hope that helps..

Comment: thank s for helping :) and yeah, " I don't remember how I solved it.." know that feeling when wading through java toolchain land...